# ViewFlipper.addView() gives Exception, while Showing Progress Dialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**What I want:** I want to show a progress dialog while adding views dynamically to my ViewFlipper.

**What I have:** I have used an AsyncTask to achieve this. The ViewFlipper is declared in my Main Activity, I am adding views to ViewFlipper in the doInBackground() of AsyncTask.

**What is the problem:**  I am getting an exception on the viewFlipper.addView() statement and the exception is " Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl ..... that was originally added here.  " , something like this.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Activity
{   

   private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main_flipper);

      viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.id_vf_main);
      new LoadData().execute();
      // Some other tasks.
   }


   class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
   {
      protected ProgressDialog  progressDialog;

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute()
      {
          super.onPreExecute();         
          progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this,"Loading", "Loading Data...", true, false);
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Object... parametros)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < Login.data_Channel_Name.size(); i++)
          {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            RelativeLayout rl_main = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null); 

            TextView tv_channelNumber = (TextView)rl_main.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_ChannelNumber);
            if(tv_channelNumber != null)
            {
                tv_channelNumber.setText("Some Number");
            }

            TextView tv_channelName = (TextView)rl_main.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_ChannelName);
            if(tv_channelName != null)
            {
                tv_channelName.setText("Some name");
            }

            viewFlipper.addView(rl_main);
          }     
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to interact with the UI from the background thread which isn't allowed. You are allowed to mess with the UI in your **onPostExecute()** and **onPreExecute()** methods. There is another method; **onProgressUpdate()** you can use like so:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
// on UI thread!
    viewFlipper.addView(rl_main);
}
```

Obviously you'll need to handle passing the view to this method by creating a field or something. You can call this within your doInBackground() with the following:

```
publishProgress(0);
```

The function is typically used for updating the percentage on a loading bar or similar (hence passing the integer) but should work fine your your purposes.

Comment: Fantastic question & answer. I could not use the onProgressUpdate() as described, instead, I loaded all the Views in an ArrayList in the onBackground() method and then in the onPostExecute() method I added them to the ViewFlipper.